# Navigate to lower level navigator from upper level component in react native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Currently, I'm working on a react native mobile app. I have a stack navigator in the App.js file. (stack 1, stack 2, stack 3). In the stack 1 component, I have a tab navigator. (Tab 1, tab 2, tab 3). My goal is to navigate the tab 1 component using a function call (navigateToTab1(  ) ) in App.js.

Any help on this task is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `useNavigation` from `@react-navigation/native`. The [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-navigation/) gives this simple example:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Button } from 'react-native';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

function MyBackButton() {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  return (
    <Button
      title="Back"
      onPress={() => {
        navigation.goBack();
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

In this example you can see the use of the `goBack()` method. To navigate from your different tabs, you could use the `navigate()` method of `useNavigation()`:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Button, View } from 'react-native';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

function MyComponent() {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  return (
    <View>
      <Button
        title="Go to my first tab"
        onPress={() => {
          navigation.navigate('MyFirstTab');
        }}
      />
      <Button
        title="Go to my second tab"
        onPress={() => {
          navigation.navigate('MySecondTab');
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Where the stack navigator is something like this:

```js
<Stack.Navigator>
    <Stack.Screen name="MyFirstTab" component={MyFirstTabScreen} options={{ title: 'My First Tab!' }} />
    <Stack.Screen name="MySecondTab" component={MySecondTabScreen} options={{ title: 'My Second Tab!' }} />
</Stack.Navigator>
```